# onmousedown in Firefox vs Chrome in Capacitive devices

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, touch

This question is more conceptual.

When the html page with the below code is accessed in a capacitive multi touch device, 
(a) in chrome browser: Recognition of user click/touch is slow.
(b) in Firefox browser: Recognition of user click/touch is pretty fast.

I understand that we need to handle `TOUCH` events if the page is intended to be used in multi touch devices.

But here what makes the below code work fast in Firefox but not in Chrome in multitouch capacitive devices.

```css
#action_triggering_element
{
width: 250px; 
height: 250px;
background-color:green;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo touch vs mouse</title> <!-- Title for the web page -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

 <!-- TOUCH event support for 'action_triggering_element' -->
 <!-- <script>  
 $(document).on('tap','#action_triggering_element' , function()   {event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();console.log('Tap event recognised!');});
 </script> -->
  
  <!-- HTML element created as 'action_triggering_element' along with support for MOUSE event -->
  <div id="action_triggering_element" onmousedown="event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();console.log('Mousedown event recognised!');">
    <b>Touch/Click here!</b>
  </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```